# svg viewBox strange behavior?

Tags: svg, viewbox

Im trying to figure out how svg viewBox work but the code below breaks all logic.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

In my reality viewBox is for defining the area of svg canvas to show in the viewport. The result of this code should be the left most little piece of circle is centered horizontaly with white space on both sides but chrome nor do firefox follow this logic.Can some one explain how this work? And sorry for my english, i hope you undestand what im trying to say.

[image]

Comment: Please change it to this: `<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>` Is this what you need?  [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: The problem it just doesnt work as intented. The default value is "xMidYMid meet" and considering my code it should center horizontally a little left-most piece of circle but its behaviour is totally wrong. I just want to know why its showing half of the circle. What is happening

Comment: The circle is 20 user units wide. The viewbox is showing only 1 first unit of the canvas. It cannot show half of the circle as Chrome and Firefox do. Its madness

Answer (score 1):

The problems here are that most of the circle is outside the viewBox (it's only 1 unit wide and the circle is 20 units wide) and the viewBox aspect ratio is not the same as the aspect ratio of its container.

The default for preserveAspectRatio is to maintain the aspect ratio rather than distorting the shape so we still need to draw a circle rather than an ellipse. Since the drawing area is square the circle will therefore draw into that square area and as the height of the viewBox is 20 we'll have a 20 x 20 area to draw into to draw a circle.

What do we do with the 1 unit viewBox width then? How do we map 0-1 to 20 units? We need to keep the middle value of the viewBox so that's 0.5.

We need to solve these equations then for x and y: (x + y) / 2 = 0.5 (keep the centre the same) and y - x = 20 (keep the width the same as the height to preserve the aspect ratio)

Doing the maths here: x + y = 1 -> y - (1 - y) = 20 -> 2y - 1 = 20 -> y = 10.5 and x = -9.5.

So we're going to display 0 - 20 for height and -9.5 - 10.5 in width which means you'll see roughly (but not quite) half a circle. You actually see slightly more than half the circle.

Comment: than viewbox must be scaled 5px wide 100px height. Where am i wrong? cant understand you comment. Dont see any logic

Comment: No, that would be preserveAspectRatio="none". See paragraph 2 in my answer.

Comment: sorry, my brain is melting, i cant undestand what is going on with this viewBox. I added picture of what it should be doing by spec and by all explanations i read. Its immposible to understand what is happening by logic because there is no logic in this.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome developers separately read the spec, implemented it and came up with the same thing so there clearly is logic, it does make sense and I've explained clearly how it works with the appropriate maths. You need to reread the second half of my answer.

Comment: your explanation doesnt help at all. I ve never had so much hard time with understanding something. I thought i understood what is viewBox, its a piece of canvas, isnt it? With viewBox you define what part of canvas you want to show in viewPort. Can you explain, i wasted 3 days already on this viewBox and still nothing.

Comment: i found the answer. Its simple - viewBox doesnt clip the canvas. Thx)

Answer (score 1):

The browsers are rendering your SVG correctly.

The `viewBox` just defines the area that should be scaled to fit the viewport.  The content is **not clipped** to the viewBox.  If there are elements outside of the viewBox, but still within the viewport, then those will be visible.

In your case, you have asked the browser to center the very left edge of the circle in the viewport.  But there is enough room for much of the rest of the circle to be visible.

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red"/>
    <rect width="1" height="20" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.3" stroke-dasharray="0.5 0.5"/>
</svg>
```